# javax.tools.JavaCompiler "arguments" arg

Tags: java, compiler-construction, arguments

So I've come across an annoying little issue between the api for javax.tools.JavaCompiler and the cmd line compiler (which are the same thing!).  I simply want to use an argument to javac like: ***-d C:\compiled\ C:\programs\HelloWorld.java ***.  This works great in cmd prompt, but my code is failing, saying that the file doesn't exist.

```
public class Test {

    private static String programsDir = "C:\\programs\\";
    private static String compiledDir = "C:\\compiled\\";
    private static String fileName = "HelloWorld.java";

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        String arguments = "-d " + compiledDir + " " + programsDir + fileName ;
        compiler.run(System.in, System.out, System.err, arguments);
    }
```

The output is:

```
javac: file not found: -d C:\compiled\ C:\programs\HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

But I can cut and paste "-d C:\compiled\ C:\programs\HelloWorld.java" into javac.  That is, **javac -d C:\compiled\ C:programs\HelloWorld.java** works.

Comment: `C:programs` --> ``\`` missing for some reason (your code shows that it is there)?

Comment: @nhahtdh Although it is in the code - not sure which is used ;-)

Comment: Sorry guys, that was a typo.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run` expects a list of args, have you tried:

```
String[] args = {"-d", compiledDir, programsDir + fileName};
compiler.run(System.in, System.out, System.err, args);
```

Comment: I think `-d` should be an argument on its own (assuming that `run` expects a list of args - never used this myself before).

Comment: Thanks assylias.  This worked, but there can't be a space after the d in "-d" as it won't recognize the flag.

Comment: @Matt8541 Amended - Never used it that way to be honest.